# best way to have overlays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to choose a random hex selector but only for certain colors?

I'm trying to recreate the following image but actually coding it.

[Image](http://donl.de/Oivc8n)

So far I have managed the following code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="group">
<div class="sub red panel">

</div><!--sub-->
<div class="sub orange">

</div><!--sub-->
<div class="sub yellow">

</div><!--sub-->
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    background:#333;
}
#group{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:500px;
   height:300px;
}
.sub{position:relative; float:left; width:96px;}

.pxl{width:7px; position:relative;float:left; height:7px; margin:1px 1px 0 0;}
.red div{background:#f00;}
.orange div{background:#f26607;}
.yellow div{background:#f5e70b;}
```

**js**

```
var pageLimit=288;

 for(var i = 1; i <= pageLimit; i++) {
  $('.sub').append('<div class="pxl"></div>' )
 }

var randint = function ( ceiling ) {
    return Math.floor( Math.random() * ceiling );
};

setTimeout(function () {
    $( '.pxl' ).each(function () {
        $( this ).delay( randint(5000) ).fadeTo( randint(10000), 0 );
    });
}, 5000 );
```

Any help is much appreciated
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynameisdonald/GHsBn/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this :

**Live example**

http://jsfiddle.net/GHsBn/8/

**Snippet Example**

```
var col;
    $('.red .pxl').each(function(i, e) {
            col = 'rgb(255,' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 150)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 150)) + ')';
            $(e).css('background', col);
        });
```

It loops through each pixel in class red, and building a random background color.

You can play around with the random values and ranges to get your desired result. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this and delete some of the strings in the array so it returns only the colors you want: http://paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/